Constant mean curvature hypersurface
Assume that $f:\mathbb{B}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function defined in the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $u(z)=|f(z)|(1-|z|^2)$ and consider $\Sigma =\{z: u(z)=c\}$. It seems to me that if $\Sigma$ has constant mean curvature, then $\Sigma$ should be a sphere. Whether this is true?

Have you tried to do the calculation?
